# External metric in GKE with rabbimq queue length not working , giving error

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use HPA based on external metric in GKE but it's giving error - 
`horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get external metric default/custom.googleapis.com|rabbitmq_queue_messages_ready/nil: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get custom.googleapis.com|rabbitmq_queue_messages_ready.external.metrics.k8s.io`

I've setup an external metric in k8 cluster that sends data to google stackdriver. This metric contains info about number of message in a rabbitmq, this queue is out-of-the-cluster. Based on queue length, i'm trying to autoscale my pods. 
Now i'm able to push the data to stackdriver and can see the metric in Metric Explorer. But when i try to use this in my HPA, it gives error.

HPA -

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: exp-anno-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: exp-anno
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 6
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metricName: "custom.googleapis.com|rabbitmq_queue_messages_ready"
      targetValue: 10
```

Comment: If you follow this [guide](https://itnext.io/kubernetes-workers-autoscaling-based-on-rabbitmq-queue-size-cb0803193cdf) do you get better results?

Comment: i've been following this link only, but somehow i'm not able to see my HPA working (that's there in the last step in the link)

Comment: Are you referring to the doc I linked, or another one you're using. If you're referring to the document I linked, it shows a screenshot in Step 3 that shows a StackDriver monitoring graph - are you able to see the metric rabbitmq_queue_messages_ready in StackDriver monitoring with any data?

Comment: Yes i can see the metric with data in stackdriver console

Comment: I would add the output of kubectl describe hpa [name] to the original post as a next step. Although not entirely your use case, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018420/difficulty-configuring-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-with-external-metric) mentions issue was fixed when "load" was applied, it might be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set `hostNetwork: true` in spec for deployment.

Reference: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/issues/315