# What is the unit of targetAverageValue for external metrics kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle for horizontal pod autoscaling?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, hpa

I referred this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53018420/6562126) to set up my HPA(Horizontal Pod Autoscaler) for google kubernetes engine(gke) workload. According to the details of that question and the details specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes) I mentioned my targetAverageValue to be 50 which should be considered 50% but when I run the command kubectl describe hpa this is the line I notice in the logs

`Metrics:                                                            ( current / target ) "kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle" (target average value):  33500m / 50`

This is my hpa yaml

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: gpu-metric
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: parabole-dj-u1
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metricName: kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle
      targetAverageValue: 50
```

It seems to be measuring using some other unit. What then should be my targetAverageValue if I want it to autoscale at 50% duty_cycle?

Adding the screenshot of the duty cycle metric from the portal like @Alberto Pau asked [duty_cycle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BzRJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is correct, HPA always shows in the mili units.
The current utilization is probably 33.5%, just divide the number with the "m" by 1000 and you get the percentages.

Comment: thanks. if I see in the google cloud portal metrics explorer then it seems duty cycle can go even above 100% but according to the definition of the duty_cycle metrics it is a number between 0 and 100. Any reason to this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with this exact metric.

Comment: @Sayak can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @AlbertoPau I have added the image to my question. You can check.

Comment: The image does not show how you obtained this graph, can you please share your monitoring filter? I think this metric could be an aggregation of more GPUs...

Comment: @AlbertoPau Yes 5 GPUs (1 GPU per node, 1 pod running on 1 node). So 5 pods running on 5 nodes. So then this percentage shown is aggregation of all GPUs duty cycle?

Comment: If you haven't filtered based on Instance ID, it might be. depends on your filter configuration.